# Matplotlib: Transformation of coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been struggling with this issue for a while now.
I simply want to transform my data in *display world*, perform some operations, and then translate back to the world coordinates.
Sounds, simple and according to the documentation should be done as follows:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
ax.plot([1,2], [1,2], "or")  
ax.set_xlim((0, 5))
ax.set_ylim((0, 5))
ax.set_axis_off()

p1 = [0, 0]
p1x, p1y = ax.transData.transform(p1)
print(f"p1x={p1x:.3f}, p1y={p1y:.3f}")
```

which results in `p1x=125.000, p1y=110.000`

- Question1: Why are these coordinates in a supposedly square image not equal?
- Question1: Why are these coordinates not 0? Where does this offset come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of the margins around your plot. The values you're printing are the coordinates of the origin inside your window.

You can remove margins with `plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, top=1, bottom=0)`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
ax.plot([1,2], [1,2], "or")  
ax.set_xlim((0, 5))
ax.set_ylim((0, 5))
ax.set_axis_off()

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, top=1, bottom=0)

p1 = [0, 0]
p1x, p1y = ax.transData.transform(p1)
print(f"p1x={p1x:.3f}, p1y={p1y:.3f}")
```

Output:

```
p1x=0.000, p1y=0.000
```

Comment: Thanks! That was not hard, actually. :-) for (5,5) I would then get (2500, 2500), right? Why is multiplied by `dpi*width, dpi*height`?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, `figsize` is given in inches and `transform` returns the "display coordinates" that depends on your dpi.  (see https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/users/transforms_tutorial.html#data-coordinates) so this is where the conversion comes from. You can convert in the other direction with `ax.transData.inverted().transform((p1x, p1y))`

Comment: Yeas sure it depends on dpi. I was expecting, for a dpi=100, that `x=5` would correspond to 500 not 2500!

Comment: `fig.get_dpi()` gets the dpi (100 in my case) and I have `x_px= x_data*dpi` I guess your dpi is higher than 100 (should be 200 according to the example in your question). I don't know how you get 2500 though, did you compute that?

Comment: I don't know any more. But setting an explicit value for dpi  (100) gives me the same value is in your case. So all is good and thanks for your tip.